# How to find index Path for a selected Collection View Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, nsindexpath

How to find index Path for a selected Collection View Cell without using didSelectItemAtIndexPath and prepareForSegue?

I am using this indexPath within AlertViewController. I dont know how to get this indexPath in AlertView Controller.

```
//Edit Selected Category
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Rename your ", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let actionOK = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)

        alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(textField: UITextField) -> Void in

            if let iP: IndexPath = self.collCategory.indexPath(for: CategoryCollectionCell) {

                print("IP \(iP)")
            }

        })

        alertController.addAction(actionOK)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: `collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems`

Comment: how you present this `UIAlertController` without user interaction? If you have some piece of code then provide.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .bottom)
}
```

Then u will get path from collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems

```
if let collectionView = self.YourCollectionView,
    let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first,
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? YourCell {
}
```

Comment: I am using your code but i didn't get index path while print.

Comment: @RahulChopra Sorry missed out one thing. You will have to set selection in didSelect delegate method. Have update answer

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4-4.2** - Returns index of cell.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cellIndex = indexPath[1] // try without [1] returns a list.
    print(indexPath[1])
    chapterIndexDelegate.didTapChapterSelection(chapterIndex: test)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution

```
private func getCurrentIndex() -> Int {
    return Int(collectionView.contentOffset.x / collectionView.frame.width)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To select cell without didSelect method then you can use Tap Gesture to detect cell.
Check below method to add gesture to cell and detect gesture.

//Add below code to collectionview cell return method

```
if let gestures = cell. contentView.gestureRecognizers {
            gestures.forEach({ (tap) in
                if tap .isKind(of: UITapGestureRecognizer.self) == true {
                    cell.contentView.removeGestureRecognizer(tap)
                }
            })
        }
let tapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(didTap(sender:)))
cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
cell.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec)
```

//Create method to detect gesture recognizer

```
func didTap(sender: UIGestureRecognizer)
{
    let cell = sender.view?.superview as! yourCell
}
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score -3):

Inside your CollectionView delegate call

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) 
    print(" Row : \(indexPath.row)")

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I want this indexPath when i select the cell.

Comment: yes exactly when you will tap on cell it will give you a specific cell no you tapped on @RahulChopra

Comment: @AvinashMishra Please explain how this answer solves the question being asked (because it doesn't).

Comment: @rmaddy this will give you a exact no of index path where you will tap in collectionView Cell thats what Question is being asked. According To me if anything else please let me know.

Comment: The question is asking how to get the index path of the selected cell. The code you posted has nothing to do with a selected cell. You posted the code used to provide cells for all items to the collection view.

Comment: @rmaddy exactly it will provide you a cell but inside in PRINT line when you will tal on specific cell it will give the cell index.

Comment: No, your code has *nothing* to do with cell selection. The `print` will not appear when a cell is selected.